# Не работает обработчик ошибки 404 в node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, mongodb, mongoose

Привет!Я учу node.js и попутно создаю свой API сервер с MongoAtlas.Я хотел сделать что если не найден продукт то вместо

```
{
    "err": {
        "message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"5ad2f3dced708e1f7ce7\" at path \"_id\" for model \"Product\"",
        "name": "CastError",
        "stringValue": "\"5ad2f3dced708e1f7ce7\"",
        "kind": "ObjectId",
        "value": "5ad2f3dced708e1f7ce7",
        "path": "_id"
    }
}
```

Будет обычное сообщение

```
{
 "message": "No valid entry found for provided ID"
}
```

Но мой код не заработал.Я проверял если `doc` буде равен не `NULL`.

```
router.get('/:productid',(req,res,next)=>{
    const id = req.params.productid;
        Product.findById(id)
        .exec()
        .then(doc => {
            console.log(doc);
            if (doc) {
                res.status(200).json(doc);
            }else{
                res.status(404).json({
                    message: 'No valid entry found for provided ID'
                });
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
            res.status(500).json({err:err})
        });
    });
```

Сейчас я получаю стандартное сообщение об ошибке.Подскажите как сделать вывод сообщение если не найден продукт по `ID`

Comment: В exec пропишите callback вида (err, doc) => {} и реализуйте там всю логику, промис можно будет убрать. Так вы сможете избавиться от перехвата ошибки.

Comment: Я не понял что такое промис. Можете обьяснить?Если я пропишу `(err, doc) => {}` то мне не нужно прописывать `.then`, `.catch`?

Comment: .then().catch() - это и есть промис. Если вы пропишите callback в exec(), то ваша ошибка не будет перехватываться и вы сможете самостоятельно ее обработать.